# how to use onresume() and onpause() for when on tabclick change event "means refresh tab content" each time click

Tags: android

when i change the tab and push again previous clicked  tab i want to reload item in it again means refresh the tab containing class with new data...so thats why i use onpause() and onresume() method but so how to delete old loaded data when i click first time on tab...and  when i click it gives array index out of bound exception..

```
  protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();


 }



protected void onResume()
{

   super.onResume();

   new ProgressTask6().execute();

}
```

Comment: _What_ gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception? I don't think you've provided enough information to be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Neil when i change the tab in a view and move to other tab and load again previous tab it fc and gives array indaex out of bound

Comment: Sure, but we need some code. We need to see the LOC that gives the error, we need some explanation as to what the array is being used for, maybe a stack trace. Need way more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go through Activity.

As far as your question is concerned, you can set up a flag for activity while you create an intent, so that each time when you click on the tab it is refreshed.